# Letting several assemblies access the same text file

Tags: c#, .net, file, file-io, filesystems

I've got many assemblies/projects in the same c#/.net solution. A setting needs to be saved by people using the web application gui, and then a console app and some test projects need to access the same file. Where should I put the file and how to access it?

I've tried using "AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory" but that ends up being different for my assemblies. Also the "System.Reflection.Assembly.Get*Assembly.Location" fail to give me what I need.

Maybe this isn't something I should but in a file, but rather the database? But it feels so complicated doing that for a few lines of configuration.

Comment: Are the assemblies all in the same directory?  

If not, nothing short of having a config file for each assembly pointing to the main config file is going to be useful

Comment: I am wondering if you are going to experience locking problems... with multiple applications trying to write the same file.

Comment: Vaibhav: Only one of the assemblies will ever write to the file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally, I would be leveraging the database because the alternative is either a configuration headache or is more trouble than it's worth.

You *could* configure each application to point to the same file, but that becomes problematic if you want to move the file. Or you could write a service to manage the file and expose that to clients, but at this point you may as well just use the DB.

Answer (score 3):

Put the file in

```
    Path.Combine(
        Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.CommonApplicationData),
        "[Company Name]\[Application Suite]");
```

Answer (score 0):

Thought about storing it in the registry or in Isolated Storage? Not sure if multiple applications can share Isolated Storage or not, though.

Comment: Not really, they need to be deployed using ClickOnce for that as it seems.

Comment: I don't know. It feels more logical and safe to put it in a database as compared to the registry. Or?

Comment: Well, I say if you have a database, then yes put them in the database for sure....

Answer (score 0):

projects can have build events -- why not add a post-build event to copy the file to all required locations?